# Razor Html Select/Option Set selected option on postback

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I have an html select with 3 options. I would like to be able to set which option is selected when my form does a post back. I am using Razor(c#), Html, Jquery, and CSS(if it helps). 
any suggestions? I would prefer not to use jquery and to do it within razor syntax but I know somethings are unavoidable.

```
        <select name="OS" id="OS">
                <option id="blank" value="">select your OS</option>
                <option id="Mac OSX" value="OSX">Mac OSX</option>
                <option id="Windows" value="PC">Windows</option>
            </select></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a strongly typed view you could just pass the selected value into your selectlist

```
new SelectList(os, Model.Os);
```

Example Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.OsList = new SelectList(osList);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(pickOsModel pickOsModel)
{
    ViewBag.OsList = new SelectList(osList, pickOsModel.Os);
    return View();
}
```

View

```
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Os, ViewBag.OsList as SelectList)%>
```